# How can I add support for angular unit tests in dotnet core angular template of Visual Studio

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my angular project in the ASP.NET Core Angular template of Visual Studio. And I have integrated this project to Azure DevOps. Now, the issue is, at the unit testing step in the Azure pipeline, it runs `dotnet test` command to run the unit tests. But I have my unit test in the angular project which is run by Karma. How can I run the angular unit tests with the same setup which I have right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [npm task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops) to run angular unit tests. For below example add npm task in your pipeline to run custom command:

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Angular Test'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: run test -- --watch=false --code-coverage
    workingDir: $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/angularFolder
```

Or you can run `npm run test` command directly in a script task. For below example:

```
- script: |
    cd $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/angularFolder
    npm test
```

You can check out the examples in below blog.

[Build and test projects in Azure DevOps pipelines](https://medium.com/@kristaps.strals/build-and-test-projects-in-azure-devops-pipelines-745abea273b8)

[Continuously Integrating Angular with Azure DevOps](https://dev.to/thisdotmedia/continuously-integrating-angular-with-azure-devops-2k9l)

[Build, test, and deploy JavaScript and Node.js apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code#run-unit-tests)

Comment: I am having this task - - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
as my project is dotnet core and in that I am using my angular project. So in pipeline, I have all my tasks of dotnetcoreCLI. Can I use npm taks along with it?

Comment: Yes, you can have npm task along with it.  DotnetcoreCLItask is for  the dotnet projects, and npm is for the angular projects. They donot conflict with each other.